# Creating a Lambda Function without using PassRole permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I try to create a lambda function, I cannot create it because, I do not have the PassRole permission. I cannot get this permission either due to security issues.

Is there anyway I can configure my IAM user around this? My IAM user cannot have any IAM permissions that allow modifying the IAM itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to create a lambda without assigning it a role.

What I would suggest is that the folks that won't let you pass a role create you a basic lambda role and give you permissions to pass just that role.

Otherwise you're dead in the water.

Comment: Agreed. They could even create an "empty role" that grants no permissions to AWS services, but lets you use the Lambda function for processing.